# WPF Fonts are set to 16, yet render at 16.8033333333333. Why?

Tags: wpf, windows

Do you know if the default unit for WPF really is in pixels?  I am seeing big differences in an HTML Page and an identical WPF page I made.  My HTML page has font-size set to 16 pixels. The WPF page from my developers has its font size set to 16 (the unit set is "default").  But the font renders bigger. Everything is rendered bigger and larger.

I snooped a text item and the font size reads 16.8033333333333.

The MSN documentation says WPF uses pixels as the default unit; so, I should be safe to see a WPF window render text at the same size in pixels as it would in an identical HTML page, right?  No.

Has anyone encountered this?  I am using a fixed windows width for my WPF at 1600px wide, so the window should not be scaling its vectors.

Comment: Your display scaling is set to 125%, pretty normal for a monitor that's 1600 pixels wide.  The dpi is 120 pixel per inch.  That makes the font 16.80333  / 96 = 0.175 inches and 0.175 x 120 = 21.000 pixels tall.  Nice round number.  You are surely just seeing 16 < 21.

Comment: Thnx, Hans.  The WPF application resolution is 1600 wide, but my screen resolution is set to 1920x1080px.   How can I get it to scale at 100%, so that font is rendered at 16px and padding that is supposed to be 48px is not rendered at 73px, etc?

Answer (score 1):

WPF measures in [Device-Independent Pixels](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/text/2009/12/11/wpf-text-measurement-units/).